# Adding a class to a fixed element whenever a background image or colour appears beneath it as the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have a fixed element (#logo-icon) that I need to add a class (.inverted) to whenever a background image is loaded into any other div that might happen to appear beneath it as the user scrolls. I can't seem to get anything to work. Thanks in advance. Here's some code:

```
// Select the target element
var logoIcon = document.querySelector('#logo-icon');

// Create a new Intersection Observer instance
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    // Check if the target element is intersecting with any other element
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // Check if the intersecting element or its children have a background image
  var intersectingElement = entry.target;
  var hasBackgroundImage = checkBackgroundImage(intersectingElement);

  if (hasBackgroundImage) {
    // Add the "inverted" class to the logoIcon element
    logoIcon.classList.add('inverted');
  } else {
    // Remove the "inverted" class from the logoIcon element
    logoIcon.classList.remove('inverted');
  }
}
  });
}, { threshold: 0.5 });

// Start observing the logoIcon element
observer.observe(logoIcon);

// Function to check if an element or its children have a background image
function checkBackgroundImage(element) {
  // Check if the element itself has a background image
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  if (computedStyle.getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none') {
return true;
  }

  // Check if any child element has a background image
  var childElements = element.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
var childComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(childElements[i]);
if (childComputedStyle.getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none') {
  return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

`

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by a particular color going beneath?

Comment: Code added above. Basically, any div that has a background image or colour that scrolls beneath the logo element will make the logo not very visible. Inverting the svg will fix that, so I want to add the class to the element whenever a non-white (default) div is passed beneath it.

Comment: I don’t understand what observing a fixed element will do for you - don’t you need to observe everything else and check when it goes beneath the logo?

Comment: There is no guarantee that inverting the logo color just because it has an image behind it will make it any more visible - the image could be very dark at that part for example. You might have better results using mix-blend-mode.

Comment: @AHaworth - using Inspector I tried mixed-blend-mode, but filter:invert(1) looks way better. The code above is from ChatGPT after several attempts to get it to work, I have no idea... Maybe there's a simpler way?

Comment: I can't see that your intersection observer ever fires - it's set on the fixed logo, what would make it fire? Does invert look better because you absolutely know that all your images are dark at the position they pass under the logo?

Comment: @AHaworth - I'm not really a coder, I just bumble through it (interface designer, sorry!), but what would you suggest to make it "fire"? Regarding the images, they will be pretty much of the same sort of tint, so I don't have any worries there. A pure css solution would have been great, but using blend modes makes the logo appear grey on a white background (instead of black). If you know a pure css way for the logo to be black (default) but white as it appears over images, that would be ideal.

Comment: This is a valid scenario. Has nobody ever wanted to do something similar before?